# Regex match truncating characters to get a false positive

Tags: c#, regex

we have a regex which we want to accept a 9 digit string or a 10 digit string that ends in a 1 or 2.

```
^3[0-9]{8}[1-2]{1}$|^3[0-9]{8}
```

Tested in Regex storm, it works perfectly (example input: 3123456781 for pass, 3123456789 for fail)

but when we code it (using following code) "Input" is the full 10 characters and "M" is only the first 9, so it passes when the fail string is entered. Not sure why this is happening

```
Regex R = new Regex(ScanExpression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match M = R.Match(Input);
if (M.Success)
{
    Results = Input;
}
```

Comment: Your premise seems to be wrong. If I test that regex in regexstorm then it passes for both your test values: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e3%5b0-9%5d%7b8%7d%5b1-2%5d%7b1%7d%24%7c%5e3%5b0-9%5d%7b8%7d&i=3123456789

Comment: Yeah, my copy/paste missed the ending '$'

Comment: Ah. Well, you've got a much neater regex out of it now anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^3[0-9]{8}[1-2]{1}$|^3[0-9]{8}` contains 2 alternatives: `^3[0-9]{8}[1-2]{1}$` that matches `3`, 8 digits and a `1` or `2` as a whole string, and `^3[0-9]{8}` matches a string starting with `3` and then any 8 digits, there is no `$` here that would require the end of string right after the 8 digits.

You might use `^3[0-9]{8}[1-2]{1}$|^3[0-9]{8}$`, or `^(?:3[0-9]{8}[1-2]{1}|3[0-9]{8})$`, but the shortest solution is

```
^3[0-9]{8}[12]?$
```

Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `3` - a `3`
- `[0-9]{8}` - any 8 ASCII digits
- `[12]?` - an optional `1` or `2`
- `$` - end of string.

See the [RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e3%5b0-9%5d%7b8%7d%5b12%5d%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=3123456781%0d%0a3123456789%0d%0a312345678%0d%0a3123456783&o=m) (note the `\r?` is added since the demo is based on a multiline string, it is not necessary when you test against separate strings).

Comment: Just FYI: `{1}` is always redundant since each unquantified atom is tried exactly once, and `[1-2]` is the same as `[12]` since there are no chars in between `1` and `2`.